# Showing that an injective $^*$-homomorphism between two $C^*$-algebras is isometric.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

**Problem:** *"Let $(A,\|\cdot\|)$ and $(B,\|\cdot\|)$ be unital $C^*$-algebras and let $\phi:A\to B$ be an injective $^*$-homomorphism. Show that $\phi$ is isometric. **Hint**: Treat the case of self-adjoint elements firstly and use the fact that it suffices to consider the case when $A$ and $B$ are commutative."*

I'll collect together the key facts that, I think, I need to use:

1. For $C^*$-algebras $(A,\|\cdot\|),(B,\|\cdot\|)$ we call $\phi: A\to B$ a $^*$*-homomorphism* if (i) $\phi$ is linear, (ii) $\phi(a_1a_2)=\phi(a_1)\phi(a_2)\,\forall a_1,a_2\in A$, and (iii) $\phi(a^*)=\phi(a)^*\,\forall a\in A$.
2. For $C^*$-algebras $(A,\|\cdot\|),(B,\|\cdot\|)$ and $\phi: A\to B$ we have that $r(a)=\|a\|\,\forall a\in A: a=a^*$, where $r(a)$ is the *spectral radius* of $a\in A$.

**Attempt:** I've made multiple attempts at this problem, and I'm not sure which, if any, are going to yield any fruit. I know that in order to show that this injective $^*$-homomorphism is isometric I need to show that $\|a\|=\|\phi(a)\|,\,\forall a\in A$.

Consider firstly those $a\in A:a=a^*$. Then we know that by the $C^*$*-property* $\|a\|^2=\|a^*a\|$ for self-adjoint $a\in A$. Then:

$$\|a\|^2=\|a^*a\|=r(a^*a)=r(a^*)r(a)=r(a)^2$$

But I don't see that this gets me anywhere, other than reiterating what I already know. **Is there a connection between $r(a)$ and $\phi(a)$ that I can make use of?** It seems to me, that in some sense, if the properties above for $\phi$ held for $r$ I might be able to get somewhere.

Alternatively, since we have an injective homomorphism we know that $\phi$ maps the identity element in $A$ to the identity element in $B$. Then, consider:

$$1=\|e_B\|=\|\phi(e_A)\|=\|\phi(a^*a)\|=\|\phi(a^*)\phi(a)\|=\|\phi(a)^*\phi(a)\|$$

And then $\phi(a)^*=b^*$ for some $b\in B:b=b^*$. Then we have that,

$$\|\phi(a)^*\phi(a)\|=\|b^*b\|=\|b\|^2$$

This, again, doesn't tell me anything that I already know.

**Can anybody direct me on how best to proceed?** In particular, in accordance with the hint, **what exactly am I being told when hinted that "it suffices to consider the case when $A$ and $B$ are commutative?**

Comment: I don't know how to answer the full question, but here's an idea regarding the hint about $A$ and $B$ commutative: quotient out the commutator. Elements of the commutator have norm $0$, so they shouldn't affect the isometry property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The points you are missing are:

- Since $a^*a$ is positive, $C^*(a^*a)$ is abelian
- Since $\phi$ is a $*$-homomorphism, its image is closed ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/435105/22857)), so we may replace $B$ with $\phi(B)$.
- Since $\phi$ is injective, $\sigma(\phi(a))\subset \sigma(a)$. Simply because $A-\lambda I$ invertible implies $\phi(A)-\lambda I$ invertible.

So, on $C^*(a^*a)$,
$$
\|\phi(a^*a)\|=r(\phi(a^*a))\leq r(a^*a)=\|a^*a\|. 
$$
Thus
$$
\|\phi(a)\|^2=\|\phi(a^*a)\|\leq\|a^*a\|=\|a\|^2,
$$
and $\phi$ is contractive. Now we can apply the above to $\phi^{-1}:\phi(A)\to A$

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to show that $\phi$ is isometric goes as follows: Using that $\lVert a \rVert$ equals its spectral radius for self-adjoint $a$, one sees that the norm on $A$ is uniquely determined. Now, define a norm
$$
\rho(a) := \lVert \phi(a)\rVert \qquad (a \in A).
$$
Then the norm $\rho$ makes $A$ into a C*-algebra. Therefore, $\rho = \lVert \cdot \lVert$. It follows that $\phi$ is isometric.

Comment: Could you clarify how, exactly, since $\|a\|=r(a)$ when $a=a^*$ we see that the norm on $A$ is uniquely determined?  Does this norm being uniquely determined mean that it's the only norm we can equip $A$ with under which the $C^*$-property holds?

Comment: It seems that  you have to verify that $\rho(A)$ is  complete first.

Comment: Yes you are right. I actually forgot about that, but one can show with bare hands that the image of a $*$-hom. between C*-algebras is again a C*-algebra, using fuctional calculus. This however makes my approach much more complicated than I hoped.

Answer (score 2):

> **Theorem.** If $\rho:A\to B$ is  an injective *-homomorphism between unital abelian C*-algebra, then \begin{align*}
> \rho^*: & K_B \mapsto K_A\\
> & \tau\mapsto \tau\circ \rho.
> \end{align*}
>   is a continuous surjection between  character spaces $K_A$ and $K_B$(also called the maximal ideal space) of $A$ and $B$.

If $A$  is not abelian, consider the unital C*-algebra $C^*(a^*a)$  generated by $a^*a$.

\begin{align*}
\|\phi(a)\| & =\sup_{\tau_B\in K_B}|\tau_B(\phi(a))|=\sup_{\tau_B\in K_B}|\phi^*(\tau_B)(a)|\\
& =\sup_{\tau_A\in K_A}|\tau_A(a)|=\|a\|.
\end{align*}

---

*Proof of the theorem.* If $\rho^* $ is not a surjection, then there is a $\tau_A\in K_A\backslash \rho^*(K_B)$. By Urysohn's lemma, there is a continuous function $f$ on $K_A$ such that $$f(\rho^*(K_B))=0,f(\tau_A)=1.$$
And by Gelfand representation, there is some $a\in A$ such that $f=\widehat{a}$.
Hence $$\tau_B\circ\rho(a)=0\forall \tau\in K_B\tag{1}$$
and 
$$\tau_A(a)=1. \tag{2}$$
By (1) $\rho(a)=0$, and thus $a=0$ since $\rho$ is an injection. But this is contradict to (2).