# Prove that $C[0, 1]$ is NOT Approximately Finite

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

The following question is from *$C^*$- Algebras by Example* written by **Kenneth R. Davidson**.  The original question is **Problem III.6** in exercises after Chapter 3.

> $\mathit{Definition}$: A $C^*$- Algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ is called approximately finite (or **AF**) iff it is the closure of an increasing union of finite dimensional subalgebras $\mathfrak{A}_k$.

Let $X$ be the Cantor set constructed by the traditional "middle-third" method. Say $J_0 = [0, 1]$, $J_1 = [0, \frac{1}{3}]\,\bigcup\,[\frac{2}{3}, 1]$ and $J_n$ be the $2^n$ disjoint intervals constructed in the same way. According to the textbook, define $\mathfrak{A}_n$ be the subalgebra of functions in $C(X)$ which are constant in $J_n$. Hence we have $C(X) = \overline{\bigcup_{n \geq 0}\,\mathfrak{A}_n}$. Here the topology is induced by the $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ norm and so is $C[0, 1]$. The question wants us to show $C[0, 1]$ can be embedded into $C(X)$ and the embedding image, as a subalgebra of $C(X)$ is not **AF**. Since $C(X) \subseteq C[0, 1]$, define $\mathcal{C}_n = \{f \in C[0, 1]\,\vert\,f$ is constant in each disjoint interval of $J_n \}$. Then I believe $\overline{\bigcup_{n \geq 0} \mathcal{C}_n} = C[0, 1]$ and let the embedding be $\iota: C[0, 1] \rightarrow C(X), f \rightarrow f \vert_X$. I can not see why the image fails to be **AF** (very likely the embedding is wrong ...).

One of the key characterization of **AF**-Algebra in the same book is:

> $\mathit{Theorem\,III.4}\,$: A $C^*$- Algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ is **AF** iff $\mathfrak{A}$ is separable and: $$(\ast) \hspace{0.2cm} \forall\,\epsilon > 0\,\text{and}\,A_1, A_2, \dots, A_n \in \mathfrak{A} \hspace{0.2cm} \exists\,\text{a subalgebra}\,\mathcal{B} \leq \mathfrak{A}\,\text{with}\,dim[\mathcal{B}] < \infty \\ \text{such that}\,d(A_i, \mathcal{B}) < \epsilon\,\forall\,1 \leq i \leq n$$

$C[0, 1]$ is separable but I can not see why $(\ast)$ fails in $C[0, 1]$ either. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Your definition of $\mathcal C_n$ does not result in a finite dimensional algebra (because any $f\in \mathcal C_n$ can vary in any way it pleases outside of $J_n$).

Comment: A simple way to see hat $C([0,1])$ cannot be an AF-algebra is to notice that every finite-dimensional commutative $C^\ast$-algebra of dimension at least $2$ has a non-trivial projection, while $C([0,1])$ does not have any non-trivial projections.

Comment: Another angle is that the spectrum of any element in $C([0,1])$ is connected. I think the only finite dimensional $C^*$ algebra where every element has a connected spectrum is $\Bbb C$, which seems like a statement that admits an elementary proof. (This is pretty much the same comment as what @MaoWao said, just in another dress)

Comment: @s.harp Thank you for your input. According to both your and MaoWao's reasons I believe $C[0, 1]$ alone do not have non-trivial finite dimensional subalgebras. What I really need to show is $\iota(C[0, 1])$, as a subalgebra in $C(X)$, which contains non-trivial projection, is not **AF**. I do need to edit the question because the part about $\mathcal{C}_n$ is not very clear.

Comment: The image of $C([0,1])$ under the restriction map is all of $C(X)$, because any continuous function on $X$ can be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @s.harp This is a good point. Then can $C[0, 1]$ be embedded into $C(X)$ as a subalgebra? Beside the original question I wonder if an **AF** $C^*$-Algebra can have a non-**AF** subalgebra.

Comment: @MaoWao Thank you for your answers. I think this answered my question. I should ask whether $C[0, 1]$ can be embedded into $C(X)$ and the image, as a subalgebra, is not **AF**. Just now s.harp mentioned that the restriction mapping is not the right embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are continuous surjective maps $k: X\to [0,1]$. For example choose a ternary expansion $x=\sum_n \frac{x_n}{3^n}$ for every $x\in X$ ($x_n\in \{0,2\}$) and let $k(x) = \sum_n \frac{x_n/2}{2^n}$. By being a bit careful about the definition you can check elementarily that this can give you a continuous surjective map.

Now define $k^*: C([0,1])\to C(X)$, $f\mapsto f\circ k$. This is obviously a $*$-morphism. Further it is injective, since if $f(k(x))=0$ for all $x\in X$ clearly $f(y)=0$ for all $y\in [0,1]$ by $k$ being surjective. Now make use of the fact that [an injective $*$-morphism between $C^*$ algebras is an isometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693128/showing-that-an-injective-homomorphism-between-two-c-algebras-is-isomet) to see that $k^*(C([0,1]))\cong C([0,1])$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now it suffices to show $C[0, 1]$ alone is not **AF**.

Answer (score 0):

The quoted theorem implies that every self-adjoint element in an AF C*-algebra can be approximated by a finite sum of orthogonal projections, i.e. such elements are dense. Evidently this is not true for $C[0,1]$.

An abelian C*-algebra is AF if and only if its spectrum is totally disconnected. So the existence of a non-AF subalgebra of an AF algebra is due to the existence of a surjection from a totally disconnected space (the Cantor set $X$) to a non-totally disconnected space (the unit interval).

A non-AF subalgebra cannot lie in a (dense, possibly) union of finite-dimensional subalgebras---otherwise it would be AF.
So the map suggested in the question cannot be an embedding.
No embedding of $C[0,1]$ into $C(X)$ can lie in the inductive system defining $C(X)$ (without its limit points).

This example also shows that the AF property is not preserved by C*-subalgebras.
It is preserved, however, by hereditary subalgebras.

Comment: This could be another good exercise. If the image of the embedding is just a hereditary subalgebra instead of an ideal, then the image, as a subalgebra, is again **AF**.